# Rails development server not logging backtrace on 500 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I recently updated my application to Rails 7.1 and the development server seems to have stopped logging error backtraces.

Example of the logs from a broken page:

```
Started GET "/coffees-subscription-choices" for ::1 at 2023-12-06 16:07:08 -0600
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by GreatCoffeesController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/about.html.erb
  Rendering great_coffees/index.html.erb within layouts/about
  Rendered great_coffees/index.html.erb within layouts/about (Duration: 31.9ms | Allocations: 7867)
  Rendered layout layouts/about.html.erb (Duration: 32.1ms | Allocations: 8006)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 12.5ms | Allocations: 11601)
```

No error message or backtrace.

I searched around a bit and applied these changes to `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_1.rb`, but to no effect :/

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = :all
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.debug_exception_log_level = :error
```

Anyone know what I might be missing?  Rails 7.0 logged the backtrace for errors as expected.

Comment: Just in case: the exceptions will be logged AFTER the `Completed 500 ...` line. You're only showing up to that line, so just putting this here on the off chance you're not thinking to look beyond that in your log setup. Are you seeing the development exception page in your browser? Or just the 500.html page?

Comment: I'm not seeing the development exception page, it's showing the production exception page.

And yeah, that's just the end of the log, there is nothing after `Completed 500..`

Comment: Hmm, you sure `Rails.env == "development"`?

Comment: Yeah, I've double checked the environment and it's development :/

Comment: See you got it sorted, well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions from Pascal, I was able to nail this down to outdated versions of `rollbar` and `web-console`.

Updating these 2 gems got my error reports in development back to expected!

```
Using web-console 4.2.1 (was 3.7.0)
Using rollbar 3.4.2 (was 3.3.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. Updating to the latest version of the Honeybadger gem fixed this problem.

Comment: Wauw I was searching for a solution for about a week. Rollbar update did the trick! Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

We had the same problem and it happened that we used an old version of a gem (sentry-raven 3.1.2) that patched the DebugExceptions middleware. Because its `render_exception` method signature changed with Rails 7.1, the patch itself caused an exception. Both the original and the additional exception are then not shown anywhere.

The solution for us was to patch the outdated gem, because we are not able to upgrade there.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I wonder if Rollbar is doing the same thing, I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: Tried upgrading Rollbar to the latest version and also removing it completely.  Neither seemed to make a difference unfortunately hmmm...

Comment: Okay!  Looks like I had to upgrade both `rollbar` and `web-console` and now it's working as expected.  Thanks for putting me on the right track!